# Expanding the powers of algebraic expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement

Suppose we have an expression like
$b^m-2 b^{1+m}+4 b^{-2+2m}$. Now is it possible to expand the powers to get
$b^m-2b b^m+4 b^{-2} b^{2m}$? Indeed, I want to replace $b^m$ with another expression, and Mathematica cannot recognize it in e.g. $b^{1+m}$.

More generally, is there a way to replace $b^{f(m)}$ with $b^{f(1)}$ where $f(m)$ is an arbitrary function of $m$?

Answer (score 1):

Does this help you?

```
ex = b^m - 2 b^(1 + m) + 4*b^(-2 + 2*m)
Simplify@ex
Simplify@ex /. Power[b, x_] :> a[x] /. b -> a[1]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you! Indeed ":>" helped me!